# replace 'a' to either number 7s or 8s recursion(python)

Tags: python, recursion

I am new to python and trying to learn the recursion.
I'm trying to display all possible outcomes by changing 'a' to either number 7 or 8

For example,

```
user_type =  40aa
```

so it will display:

```
4077

4078

4087

4088
```

thank you

it doesn't have to be 40aa, it can be a4a0, aaa0, etc

this code is only replace 7, how can i fix that

```
user_type = 40aa
def replace(string, a, b)
   if not string:
       return ""
   elif string[:len(b)] == b: 
       return a + replace(string[len(b):], a, b)
   else: 
       return string[0] + replace(string[1:], a, b)
print(replace(user_type, '7', 'a'))
```

Comment: Because in the parameters you passed only 7?

Comment: how do i pass more than 1 in that function, got no idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
pattern = "40aa"
options = [7, 8]

def replace(left, right):
   if len(right) > 0:
      if right[0] == "a":
         results = []
         for i in options:
             results.extend(replace(left + str(i), right[1:]))
         return results
      else:
         return replace(left + right[0], right[1:])
   else:
      return [left]

print replace("", pattern)
```

In other words, the function is called with the already processed part of the pattern, and remaining part of the pattern. If the next pattern's character is a digit, it's passed from the pattern to the result. If it's "a" it's replaced with all options step by step and the remaining pattern is processed recursively.

Comment: `options` could be made a function parameter as well.

Comment: OP could benefit from some explanation of what the code does, and why his code doesn't work.

Comment: could you please explain what is this line does? results.extend(replace(left + str(i), right[1:]))

Comment: @Besttee The line in question extends the `results` list with a list obtained as a result of the `replace` function call. Considering we have `left = "40"` and `right = "aa"`, this function is called in this way: `replace("407", "a")` and then `replace("408", "a")`.

Comment: Thank you very much, why do u have [left] in bracket?

Comment: The function is expected to always return a list, otherwise the `results.extend` would not work. If I have only a single value available I have to create a single-item list in this way.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Python very well, but I can help with the recursion.
The basic idea is that you will loop through each character in the string, and each time you hit an 'a', you will replace it with a 7 and an 8, and pass both of those values to your recursive method.

Here is an example:
Suppose you have the string "Basttaa".

Loop until you hit an a, so you are at the second character. Replace it with a '7' and an '8'. Now you have two separate strings, and you can pass both to your recursive method.

We now have "B7sttaa" and "B8sttaa". We pass both to our function.
In the first string, we get to the 6th character and replace it with a '7' and an '8' and repeat the process. After that replacement, we have "B7stt7a", "B7stt8a", and "B8sttaa".

Now with the second string that was passed, we get to the 6th character again and do the process of replacing. Now we have four strings: "B7stt7a", "B7stt8a", "B8stt7a", and "B8stt8a".

Those four strings are again passed to the recursive method and we get our final 8 strings, after the last character on each is replaced with both a '7' and an '8'.

Our four strings: "B7stt7a", "B7stt8a", "B8stt7a", and "B8stt8a" are again passed to our recursive method. The method gets to the last character of each, and replaces the a of each with a '7' and '8'. Then, because it is at the end of each string, it adds each to the list.

"B7stt7a" becomes "B7stt77" and "B7stt78" and both are added to the list.

"B7stt8a" becomes "B7stt87" and "B7stt88" and both are added to the list.

"B8stt7a" becomes "B8stt77" and "B8stt78" and both are added to the list.

"B8stt8a" becomes "B8stt87" and "B8stt88" and both are added to the list.

Now the list has ["B7stt77", "B7stt78", "B7stt87", "B7stt88", "B8stt77", "B8stt78", "B8stt87", "B8stt88"]

The psuedo-code looks something like this:

```
list[];
recusion(string str)
    for each char
        if char is 'a'
            return recursion(str replace char with 7)
            return recursion(str replace char with 8)
        if at end
            add str to list
    return;
```

Comment: There are 2 `return` statements, the latter one would never be executed I guess ?

Comment: The latter is executed. Once the recursion goes through all the characters, and hits the end, then all 'a''s have been replaced and the work is done. Then that return ends the function calls.

Comment: it supposed to replace all 'a' with 7 and/or 8,  if 'Basttaa' then it will be B7stt77>B7stt87>B7stt88>B8stt77>so on

Comment: That's what the final 8 strings become. I didn't show that, because I thought at that point it was clear. I'll add in that explanation.

Answer (score 0):

So, we can do this in a fairly straightforward way. We need to create two lists:

```
user_type.split('a') == ['40', '', '']
itertools.product('78', repeat=user_type.count('a')) == [('7', '7'), ('7', '8'), ('8', '7'), ('8', '8')]
```

Now, for each of our pairs, we need to interleave them. The `itertools` documentation provides a nice recipe named `roundrobin()` to do this:

```
import itertools

# Round Robin recipe from the itertools documentation
def roundrobin(*iterables):
    "roundrobin('ABC', 'D', 'EF') --> A D E B F C"
    # Recipe credited to George Sakkis
    pending = len(iterables)
    nexts = itertools.cycle(iter(it).next for it in iterables)
    while pending:
        try:
            for next in nexts:
                yield next()
        except StopIteration:
            pending -= 1
            nexts = itertools.cycle(itertools.islice(nexts, pending))
```

Let's put all of this together:

```
user_type = "40aa"
user_count = user_type.count('a')

for replacement in itertools.product('78', repeat=user_count):
    print ''.join(roundrobin(user_type.split('a'), replacement))
```

Which outputs:

```
4077
4078
4087
4088
```

Comment: I try not to use any import because I'm trying to learn python steps by steps, but thank you very much. I will keep this method in mind